# $.getJSON not working with MAMP

Tags: jquery, json, localhost, mamp

I've looked through a ton of `$.getJSON()` posts on here to see if any of them can help me with my problem, however nothing has seemed to help so far.

Putting together a webpage locally using MAMP. jQuery is working fine locally, however as soon as I wrap anything in `$.getJSON()`, even a simple alert, nothing seems to work.

The data I want to pull is from a locally hosted MySQL database so there's no calling cross-sites. I thought the problem could be a MIME issue, however I've added `application/json json` and still nothing.

I don't think there's anything wrong with my code, however this is it just incase:

```
$.getJSON("test.php", function(data) {
  if (data.test.length > 0) {
    $('.title').empty();
    $('.content').empty();
    $.each(data.test, function() {
      var info = '';
      if(){
      } else {}
      $('').append(info);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean, "nothing seems to work"? Do you get console errors? What does your browser's Network panel say about the request? What do you get if you simply call `test.php` as a document in your browser (from the address bar)?

Comment: Sorry, I mean nothing within $.getJSON() is called. There's no console errors, it's almost as if the call has been ignored. `test.php` is a PHP request to the database; when I call from the browser I get the required JSON file as I would expect.

Comment: That's my point - look at the developer tools network panel to see whether the network call has occurred or not. Also, put a `console.log` outside the `if`, right at the beginning of your handler, to see if it is getting called at all.

Comment: I've added a `console.log('Success');` and it doesn't get called when checking via developer tools.

Comment: If the success function is not called, then your problem probably is a server-side error (in which case the success function is not called). Try appending a .error(function() { alert('Server Error') }) to the object returned by $.getJSON() and see if the alert pops up.

Comment: Also, can't stress this enough, this being the third time I'm writing this: check the network panel of Firebug or Developer Tools to see what exactly happened.

Comment: I think I may have worked out what is going on here. When I make the JSON call, the content type of the script is changed from `application/x-javascript` to `text/plain`. Now to find a way of stopping it.

Comment: Okay so my estimation was incorrect. I appended `.error()` and now get a 'Failure' message, however I still don't get a console read out. I am completely stumped with this now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this really was as simple as my JSON data was not being served up correctly. For some reason, an extra colon was being added to end of each array and my code couldn't read it.

So, as people commented above, this was a server-side issue.